# Including content of php page into another

Tags: php, html

I know what to use and how.
Here is my script:

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="top:230px; right:50px">  // Style does not work
<?php include 'index.php'; ?>
</div>

<h1>Welcome to my home page.</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php contains this page:

http://yepinol.com/wall/

I want to place this content as specifi height, and location on the page. For that I added style as above. But it's height and left right position does not change?

Why?
index.php - [source code of index.php](https://github.com/karimkhanp/commentbox_quora/blob/master/yepinol/Wall/index.php)

Comment: Are you trying to include the whole page, as if it is inside an iframe?

Comment: inside `div` not iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) css attribute you need to add `position`. It has no effect on non-positioned elements.So do, like:

```
position: relative;
```